# CDate for Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, firefox, date

I have been using **CDate** in my program and the worry part is , it works only in IE.
`cdate(strValue) .` If I pass the value of **strvalue** as 01/02 , it returns as **Wed Jan 2 etc** . Am looking for the same implementation in javascript so that it will work in other browsers. Am trying my best to find one, but am not lucky. Can anyone tell me what api we can use in javascript instead of using CDate ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
var comp = "05/04".split('/');
var m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
var d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
var date = new Date(null, m - 1, d);
date.toDateString();   //this line will return the date
```

Now you can parse the string and manipulate string according to your need.